# Solve for $A$ if $\sin 2x-\cos2x= \sqrt{2} \sin(2x+A\pi)$, then the number $0<A<2$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $A$: if
 $\sin 2x-\cos2x= \sqrt2 \sin(2x+A\pi)$,
then $0<A<2$.

I tried it with trigonometry identities and algebra but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin2x-\cos2x=\sqrt2\left\{\sin2x\cos\left(2m\pi+\dfrac\pi4\right)-\cos2x\sin\left(2m\pi+\dfrac\pi4\right)\right\}$$
$$=\sqrt2\sin\left\{2x-\left(2m\pi+\dfrac\pi4\right)\right\}$$ where $m$ is any integer