# Solve for $A$ if $\sin 2x-\cos2x= \sqrt{2}\sin(2x+A\pi)$; is then $0<A<2$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for $A$ if $\sin 2x-\cos2x= \sqrt{2}\sin(2x+A\pi)$.

I tried it with trigonometric identities but I can't solve it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008102/solve-for-a-if-sin-2x-cos2x-sqrt2-sin2xapi-then-the-number-0a2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take a look at [this](http://dspguru.com/sites/dspguru/files/Sum_of_Two_Sinusoids.pdf): it is a small document on someone encountering almost the exact same problem as you. However, it does use complex numbers, so it requires you to be familiar with those.

Howeve,r as you are only interested in the value of $A$, and perhaps not why the identity is true, you could use the following tactic: if the left hand side is equal to the right hand side, then the should be equal for $x = 0$ as well. What can you conclude with this? Does this already uniquely determine $A$ (up to the period of the sine function)?